# Qt QGraphicView and QGraphicScene mouse position

Tags: c++, qt, graph, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have project which display inner structure of ELF binary files. I use QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene. So I can display blocks on graphics scene, but I need after mouse click on single block display content of this block. I am trying use function:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
   ui->textEdit->append(QString("x = %1, y = %2").arg(event->Pos().x()).arg(event->Pos().y()));
}
```

But position is tracking in whole window. Problem is, that width and height of window is dynamical and height of QGraphicsScene may be greater than window's. So I can't track single block.

I tryed some function like:
mapFromScene, mapToScene, mapFromGlobal, ... but I don't know, how theese functions works, but position what I get wasn't right.

It occurred to me that position should be calculated by scrollbar of QGraphicalView and size of window, but it's hard to calculated precisely and it's not correct solution.

Some idea, how get true position on graphic scene? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want. All of these coordinate systems are relative to each other and for any given implementation of mousePressEvent, either for widgets or for scene items, you'll be working in that object's coordinate system. If you want the mouse event in scene coordinates, then reimplement QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent. If you want them in view coordinates, them reimplement QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent, and so on. I would read "true position on graphic scene" as implying that QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent is the right place, but it's not clear.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Why handle events on the top-level window? The purpose of the graphics scene system is to provide items that you can interact with. You can have all sorts of interaction with the items themselves - they were designed to make that easy.

Comment: Beacause I am noob with Qt, I don't know Qt and it's my first advanced GUI app.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this problem with make my object, which inherit QGraphicView (MyQGraphicView) and then I declared function mousePressedEvent for this object. This help me.

Answer (score 4):

QGraphics, like other graphics frameworks, uses multiple coordinate systems and you need to consider which system you're working in when dealing with coordinates.

We can think of a `QGraphicsScene`as a world, within which there are objects that are represented by `QGraphicsItem`s ( or `QGraphicsObject'`s. if you want them to use signals and slots).

To view an area of the world, we use one or more `QGraphicsView`s.

In order to map between the different coordinate systems, Qt provides the useful mapTo and mapFrom functions.

Starting at the top, with a QGraphicsView, we can convert a coordinate and use `QGraphicsView::mapToScene` to get the coordinate in the scene's coordinate system. From this, if an item resides at that coordinate, we can get the coordinate relative to the item, using `QGraphicsItem::mapFromScene`.

So, with the three levels (view, scene and item) think about which system the coordinate is in and where you want to be dealing with it.

> how get true position on graphic scene?

Hopefully you should now be thinking that the coordinate you have been provided in the MainWindow is in the view's coordinate system and you can **map to** the **scene's** coordinate system.

```
QPointF scenePoint = mapToScene(event->Pos());
```

However, this is overcomplicating things and you'll find it easier to work directly with the scene and the items it contains, by overloading the item's own mouseMove/Press/Release events, which provide `QGraphicsScene` coordinates.